# Could not find method mavenDeployer() for arguments

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle

Why my application is not installed properly in my device.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Aniket\Documents\rust\mobileapp-development-695c58f9c0835c55acd463aabc3eec87b2cbbe55\node_modules\react-native-appearance\android\build.gradle' line: 132
- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-appearance'.
> > Could not find method mavenDeployer() for arguments [build_1x0u9twqc721dtuhwuvmg7434$_run_closure5$_closure16$_closure18@599e5b40] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

Comment: got any luck with it?